# Update database data inside a Rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is possible to update database data inside a migration?

I have this migration:

```
class FixTokenAuth < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    unless column_exists? :users, :provider
      add_column :users, :provider, :null => false
    end
    unless column_exists? :users, :uid
      add_column :users, :uid, :null => false, :default => ""
    end
    unless column_exists? :users, :tokens
      add_column :users, :tokens, :text
    end
  end
end
```

And I have also to add indexes

```
add_index :users, [:uid, :provider],     :unique => true
```

Of course the migration fail: uid is "" per default and it can't be unique.

After the creation of the column I need to execute a block on my User model:

```
User.all.each{|u|
  u.provider = "email"
  u.save!
}
```

Doing this 'uid' field is filled by data.

Is possible to add something to a migration?

Comment: If you're updating the `provider` field of all the users to a default value, why not use a default value?

Comment: you are right, i put email default but I have to save all users to generate uid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migration is just plain ruby code, which gets executed, so the best thing you could do is change the `change` method into [`up` and `down`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html). In these methods you can safely write your updating code after the `add_column`statements.

Comment: Don't forget to use [User.reset_column_information](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/reset_column_information)